# Filling null vals in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I Have a column like this

Jacob

NaN

NaN

Max

NaN

Prince

NaN

NaN

NaN

I want to fill NaN vals like this

Jacob

Jacob

Jacob

Max

Max

Prince

Prince

Prince

Prince

Help Please

Comment: Use `df.ffill()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one :

```py
df['col_name'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: bingo! that's exactly what i wanted. You're great